# Going from sort to order and back

Tags: r, sorting, vector

`sort` and `order` return a vector of ordered values and indices of ordered values respectively.

It's simple to use `order` to implement `sort`:

```
v <- c(17, -5, 1, 20)

identical(v[order(v)], sort(v))
```

> [1] TRUE

What's the most straightforward way to use `sort` to implement `order`?

Here's what I came up with:

```
identical(sapply(sort(v), function(x) grep(paste0("^", x, "$"), v)), order(v))
```

> [1] TRUE

Not pretty. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `identical(match(sort(v), v), order(v))`

Comment: Note that the solution in the question depends on there being no duplicates.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, `identical(match(make.unique(as.character(sort(v))), make.unique(as.character(v))), order(v))` might take care of duplicates

Comment: Thanks d.b! Good catch @G.Grothendieck. `make.unique` is needed as in d.b's comment.

Comment: Sorry. You are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the index in the `sort` function:

```
sort(v, index.return=TRUE)
#$x
#[1] -5  1 17 20

#$ix
#[1] 2 3 1 4        # this is the order to sort the vector
```

---

```
identical(sort(v, index.return=TRUE)$ix, order(v))
# [1] TRUE
```